# How do I write code to get through NAT in a similar way to Skype?

Tags: firewall, network-protocols, nat

Does anyone knows, how skype redirect NAT and FireWalls?

Comment: Why not edit your question to be something more like "How do I write code to get through NAT in a similar way to Skype"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Skype uses a variant of the [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) protocol to traverse NAT.

You can find example C# code to implement a STUN client [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/STUN_client.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, are there any examples how to use that lib?

Comment: Depends what language you want - I've added a link to a C# example.

Comment: BTW why not re-tag with "protocols" rather than "Skype", or you might get accused of asking non-programming questions ;-)

Comment: Programming language is Python. Maybe, you have an example for it? =).

Comment: are there any C# implementation of STUN server?